# Latex: Why bottom margin in following page isn't appropriate?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

why my bottom margin doesn't change in appropriate size whatever I do in the geometry package or in .cls file ?? [image: footer in following page]

I want the footer in following page not so in borderline in the paper .. can anyone help me please .. thanks in advance .. and this is the footer in first page

[image]

this is the packages I use in .tex file

> ```
> \usepackage[margin=1.5cm, includeheadfoot, showframe]{geometry}
> ```

and this is what I write in .cls file about header and footer

> ```
> \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
> \fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
> \fancyhf{} % clear all six fields
> \rhead{{\large \textbf\@journalname} \\Vol. \@vol,~No. \@no,~\@months~\@years, Hal. 
> \@pagefirst \textendash \@pagelast \\ \@eissn}
> \cfoot{\thepage}
> \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
> }
>
> \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
> \fancypagestyle{followingpage}{%
> \fancyhf{} % clear all six fields
> \rhead{JURNAL VARIAN \lvert \@eissn}
> \lhead{\thepage \hspace{0.5em} \lvert \@firstauthor}
> \lfoot{Vol. \@vol,~No. \@no, \@months~\@years, Hal.  \@pagefirst \textendash \@pagelast\\
> DOI: \@DOI}
> \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
> \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.7pt}
> }
> \pagestyle{followingpage}
> \AtBeginDocument{\label{FirstPage}}
> \AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}
> ```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: thank you Sir .. sorry I'm new to this .. can you please help about my footer problem ..

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot without a full but minimal piece of code that demonstrates your problem. We have no idea what is causing your problem as we don't have access to a full minimal example that we can copy and test and which should show the problem. Btw isn't a margin of 1.5cm rather small? Then each line of text becomes very long which is hard to read

Comment: Look at the `.log` file. It will pobably tell you that `\headheight` and/or `\footskip` are too small. Make them as big as the message says and then check if you get what you want.

Comment: With only 1.5 cm of bottom margin, plus the default `footskip` space, plus two lines ...well, what you expected? with some like `bmargin=15cm,footskip=1mm` sure that you can use even bigger footers.

Comment: hi @daleif .. sorry, can I send the .cls and .tex file to you if you don't mind to check it, what's wrong with my working .. cause anything I do it still doesn't change .. the vspace of footer in first page is difference with the following page ..

Comment: You can, but it is better to post it here to help others in the future.

Comment: @daleif yeah sure I want it too, but I don't know how to do it .. I'm new to this .. how to share .cls and .tex here ?